# C++ simple http server, the program closes on the second request and does not send the contents of the string

Tags: c++, boost, server, asio, boost-beast

this is what my fileCollector looks like, it just stores a "cache" of files (so that you don't read the file during each request)

```
class FileCollector
    {
    public:
        FileCollector();
        std::string get_file_data(std::string s);
    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::string> fileData;
    };
```

The error is most likely here, but due to inexperience I can't find it.

```
http_connection::http_connection(tcp::socket socket, std::shared_ptr<Collector::FileCollector> fc)
        : socket_(std::move(socket)),
        filecollector(fc)
    {}

    void http_connection::start(void)
    {
        read_request();
    }

    void http_connection::read_request(void)
    {
        auto self = shared_from_this();

        http::async_read(
            socket_,
            buffer_,
            request_,
            [self](beast::error_code ec,
                std::size_t bytes_transferred)
            {
                boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
                if(!ec)
                    self->process_request();
            }
        );
    }

    void http_connection::process_request(void)
    {
        response_.version(request_.version());
        response_.keep_alive(false);

        switch (request_.method())
        {
            case (http::verb::get):
                response_.result(http::status::ok);
                response_.set(http::field::server, "Beast");
                create_response();
                break;
            default:
                response_.result(http::status::bad_request);
                response_.set(http::field::content_type, "text/plain");
                beast::ostream(response_.body())
                    << "Invalid request-method '"
                    << std::string(request_.method_string())
                    << "'";
                break;
        }
        write_response();
    }

    void http_connection::create_response(void)
    {
        std::string_view sv = request_.target().substr(1);
        std::string targetfile = {sv.data(), sv.size()};
        
        beast::ostream(response_.body())
            << filecollector->get_file_data(targetfile);
    }

    void http_connection::write_response(void)
    {
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        response_.content_length(response_.body().size());
        http::async_write(
            socket_,
            response_,
            [self](beast::error_code er, std::size_t bytes_trans)
            {
                self->socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, er);
            }
        );
    }
```

the way I start connections

```
void ownHTTPServer::start_acceptor(tcp::acceptor& accepter, tcp::socket& sock,
    std::shared_ptr<Collector::FileCollector> &fc)
{
    accepter.async_accept(sock,
        [&](beast::error_code er){
            if (!er)
            {
                std::make_shared<ownHTTPServer::http_connection>
                    (std::move(sock), std::move(fc))->start();
            }
            start_acceptor(accepter, sock, fc);
        });
}
```

g++ -IC:\boost\include\boost-1_84 -lws2_32 -lwsock32 ...
compliler x86_64-w64-mingw32

the code works if you don't use filecollector and the response content is const char*

If it's not difficult for someone, I would like to read articles on how boost.asio works

Comment: Usage note: It's not often that you get a good answer with snippets of code. Prefer to include a [mre] in your question, something those of us out here can drop into our tools, build without making any changes, run, and (hopefully, there's a bit of fuzziness around Undefined Behaviour) see what you see.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm frequently the odd one out: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6d3a67b9128975e - free code review, @ SimpleBoy

Comment: @sehe I'm not really sure where I fit in the ideological struggle between help people now, clean up later and maintain a clean-and-concise database by rejecting marginal questions. Way I see it, if someone, me included, can write a good answer, one that will help future askers make the connections the asker left out of the question, to marginal questions, let them. All I'm asking for is something that'll help more than just the asker.

Comment: @user4581301 I think there is room for both, and some tags are just way more prone to tutoring/toubleshooting kind of questions. E.g. for a bare language tag those questions never (rarely) have any value. For libraries, frameworks or even applications of methodology it’s very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `start_acceptor()`, each time a new client is accepted, you are creating a new `http_connection` object and *moving* (not *sharing*) ownership of your `shared_ptr<FileCollector> fc` object into that connection:

```cpp
std::make_shared<ownHTTPServer::http_connection>
                    (std::move(sock), std::move(fc))->start();
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus, `fc` loses access to the `FileCollector` object in memory, making it unavailable when subsequent connections transfer `fc` again and again.

You should not be using `std::move()` to transfer ownership of a `std::shared_ptr`, that defeats the whole point of using *shared* ownership.

Your `http_connection` constructor takes the `shared_ptr` *by value*, as it should.  So, simply do not use `std::move()` when passing `fc` to that constructor, let `fc` be copied so the `FileCollector` object is properly shared across multiple `shared_ptr` instances:

```cpp
std::make_shared<ownHTTPServer::http_connection>
                    (std::move(sock), fc)->start();
                                      ^^
```

Along those same lines, you should also be *capturing* `fc` *by value*, not *by reference* (just as you do with `self` in `http_connection::read_request()`), eg:

```
accepter.async_accept(sock,
    [&,fc](beast::error_code er){
       ^^
        if (!er)
        {
            std::make_shared<ownHTTPServer::http_connection>
                (std::move(sock), fc)->start();
        }
        start_acceptor(accepter, sock, fc);
    });
```

That way, the `FileCollector` object is shared properly while the `async_accept()` handler is waiting to be called.